# Artifactory trash contains lots of empty folders

Tags: artifactory

We have a mechanism in place that deletes artifacts from Artifactory (Cloud) on a regular basis meaning our trash is quite big. It uses 33% of our total storage.

The retention policy of the trash is set to 14 days. When I look at the trash can I notice a lot of empty folders. I assume they are empty because nothings is visible when I expand them in the UI and when I use the REST call `https://<my_organization>.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/storage/auto-trashcan?list&deep=1&listFolders=1&mdTimestamps=1&includeRootPath=1` the sizes shows as -1.

I have more than 100k "empty" folders in the trash.

Why are they here and should I worry about those?

Comment: Can you add the Artifactory system property `artifactory.keep.trashcan.empty.folders=false` and see if it helps?

Comment: Can I do that on a SaaS intance of JFrog?

Comment: No.. This has to be handled by JFrog. Open a support request on this

Comment: Ok thanks! I will :-)
Do you know any good reason to keep the empty folders?

Comment: There is some history behind this but the short version seems to be the ability to trace versions that were deleted and leave kind of a breadcrumb for them...